# Buying Mercenaries in Dawn Of Heroes

Tags: dawn-of-heroes

Just started the game and I was wondering if hiring Mercenaries were worth it or if the story provides me with better alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more mercenaries you get, the more amount of strategies you will be able to do. Despite of the gold farming (that is a bit boring), totally worth it imo.

Comment: I had thought initially that they were much like other games where mercs are random.